# How to find last index of foreach loop in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

How to get last index value of foreach loop in smarty,i m new for smarty I have used this code but its not working

```
{foreach from=$cityList key=myId item=i name=foo}
 {$i.location_name}{if $main_smarty.foreach.foo.last}<hr>{else}-{/if}
  {/foreach}
```

i want that when their is last city name after this its come horizontal line otherwise its like india-USA-Japan- but at last it come Japan-china

In .php i use

```
<?php
include_once('Smarty.class.php');
$main_smarty = new Smarty;

query to find citylist
$main_smarty->assign('cityList',$cityList);
?>
```

Comment: please provide more code, so we can determine the problem, the snippet you are providing looks okay to me and should work fine

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're looking for this one:

```
{foreach from=$cityList key=myId item=i name=foo}
    {if $smarty.foreach.foo.last}
        <p>This is the last item from the array!</p>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

As you see, the property you need to check is `$smarty.foreach.foo.last` where `foo` is the name of your object.

Comment: what is $smarty here can i use something else at that place like i use $main_smarty And in .php i assign $main_smarty->assign('cityList',$cityList);

Comment: As far as I know, `{$smarty}` is a reserved variable and you should use it. It shouldn't matter if your php object is named differently. You can find more about `{$smarty}` here: http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.variables.smarty.php

Comment: their is any other method to find it

Answer (score 5):

I think newer versions of Smarty have a newer technique of solving this problem than what the other answers show. The example from the [latest docs](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.last) (at the time of writing) is using the `@last`-property. You can use it like this: `{if $item@last}...`
Complete example:

```
{* Add horizontal rule at end of list *}
{foreach $items as $item}
  <a href="#{$item.id}">{$item.name}</a>{if $item@last}<hr>{else},{/if}
{foreachelse}
  ... no items to loop ...
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 4):

If $arr is the array you passed to the {foreach}, this will do the trick:

```
{$arr|@end}
```

In fact, it does not have to be called inside a {foreach}

Answer (score 2):

```
{foreach from=$foo item=$bar name=foo}
    {if $smarty.foreach.foo.last}
        Total of({$smarty.foreach.foo.total}) Items <br />
        Data ({$bar})
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually worked for me:

```
{$myvar=$someArray@end}
{$myvar.someproperty}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

## PHP

```
Array
(
    [0] => car
    [1] => toy
    [2] => cat
    [3] => gun
    [4] => dog
)
```

## .tpl

```
{foreach from=$interest key=$key item=$item}
    {$item.value}{if $key < ($interest|count - 1)}, {/if} 
{/foreach}
```

## Result

```
My interest: 
car, toy, cat, gun, dog
```

Comment: Last item: `{if $key >= ($interest|count - 1)}.{/if}`